# Lightdm, x11vnc two seats: VNC keyboard/mouse input only works if seat is active

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, vnc

I have Lightdm setup to run two seats:

- XBMC (Seat:0) which uses my monitor
- xfce (Seat:1) which uses virtual terminal 8

This way I can switch between them using Crtl-Alt-F7/F8

I use x11vnc to connect to display 1 (xfce) via VNC
`/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -o /tmp/x11vnc.log -display :1 -xkb`

So far so good. I can connect via VNC to xfce but my mouse and keyboard input is not recognized if the display of my server shows XBMC. If I switch to virtual terminal 8 (Ctrl-Alt-F8) using the server keyboard then VNC will work. This is not ideal. I want XBMC to be always be displayed on my monitor and access xfce only via VNC.

There seems to be some kind of problem which prohibits keyboard/mouse input over VNC if the virtual terminal is not active on the host.

Any ideas?

PS: I used -dk -dp to check if the keyboard and mouse inputs arrive at x11vnc and they do. So that's not the issue.

**UPDATE1:** As a workaround I found the command `chvt` which changes the virtual terminal. This way I can login using SSH and switch to XFCE with `chvt 8`. After that VNC works as expected. Once I'm done I can switch back to XBMC with `chvt 7`.